# No tests found for given includes in Jenkins

Tags: java, gradle, jenkins, junit

I facing issue  `No tests found for given includes: [**/*Test*](include rules)` in `jenkins`.

On my local when I run the test cases through `IntelliJ Idea`, they are running fine.

I check for below possibilities already -

1. Test class is in same package structure of main class.
2. Using `Junit5`, so import I am using `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

not sure IntelliJ version is matter here but I am using `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)`

Other classes test cases are working fine on `Jenkins`. I have added new test cases for new class which are failing.